# How to prove the two subsequences $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ of the alternating harmonic series are adjacent?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $u_n = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}  - \frac{1}{4}+  ..... + \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $ for $ n \geq 0$, show that $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ are adjacent.

Showing that $u_{2n}$ is decreasing and that $u_{2n+1}$ is increasing is easy.

The problem is showing that they have the same limit. If we try to find the limit of $u_{2n+1}-u_{2n}$ we find $\lim (u_{2n+1}-u_{2n}) = +\infty$ because you just get back the regular harmonic series. And $\lim (u_{2n}-u_{2n+1}) = -\infty$, well, because it is $-\lim (u_{2n+1}-u_{2n}) = -\infty$.

Some googling and searching on the site gave me that the limit of this series in $\ln(2)$. But it uses some test that are not in my introductory course!

How can I show that they have the same limit?

Comment: Actually $$|u_{2n+1}- u_{2n}|= \frac{1}{2n+1} \to 0$$ You have a sum with $2n+1$ terms, and you cancel the first $2n$ terms, leaving only the last term which is infinitesimal.

Comment: @Crostul I dont think so, $u_{2n}$ is negative, so $1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + ....$ - $(-1/2 - 1/4 - ....)$ should sum up to the harmonic series.

Comment: @mmmmhmmmmmh Complicated expressions like $u_{2n+1}$ can be deceptive. Can you tell me what is $u_5$? Also, what is $u_4$? Also, what is the difference between them?